# android.os.DeadObjectException error while creating a mp3player

Tags: android

While I was creating a simple mp3player with only a Stop button , when I run the code , android.os.DeadObjectException error pops out , I am unable to find out the reason behind this. Please do reply if you can figure out.
Thanks in advance. Following is the code and the latter one is the LogCat view.

```
package com.songs.playit;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private final static String sdPath = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    MediaPlayer mp =new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        updatePlaylist();

     Button StopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);
        StopPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){          

            public void onClick(View v){
            mp.stop();
            }       

    });
    }
    private  void updatePlaylist() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File home = new File(sdPath);
           if(home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length>0){
        for(File file: home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter())){
            songs.add (file.getName());
                    }
        ArrayAdapter<String> songList= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this , R.layout.songs_item);
        setListAdapter(songList);   
           }
    }


    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list , View v , int position , long id){
        try{
            mp.reset();
                  mp.setDataSource(sdPath + songs.get(position));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }


  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  }
}
  class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        {
        return (filename.endsWith(".mp3"));
    }

    }


}
```

Here is the Logcat View

```
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664):  at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1366)
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:410)
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664):  at android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy.performReceive(IIntentReceiver.java:124)
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.scheduleRegisteredReceiver(ActivityThread.java:816)
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664):  at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:394)
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
08-18 12:37:12.810: E/JavaBinder(664):  ... 1 more
```

Comment: DeadObjectExceptions occur when you try to access a service in another application that has been terminated.  You'll see a lot of these in logs when service crash (writing keyboards I see it all the time when my keyboard crashes).  This sounds like something died, maybe your media player?

Comment: But how can I check that?? Completely confused..